# jquery validation and changing of div content

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I am having name, email in content of a html page. i have to validate it on clicking continue button. and also the content in the content div has to change. how can i do both on clicking the continue button. help me with some suggestions. thanks.
am using the following code for changing div content.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        $("#content").load("<?php echo base_url().'survey/categories' ?>");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#content").load("<?php echo base_url().'survey/budget_overview' ?>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: "Jsfiddle" helpful to understand your question. Please make a "Jsfiddle" example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your syntax. You have to specify a file URL in the load method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $("#content").load("myfile.php");
        return false;
    });
});
```

You can have a look on the [load documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: on button click i need to validate name and email

Comment: So you want to validate a form ?

Comment: But when you validate a form, the page need to be reload. Ok I understand.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question, i think what you want is to do the two tasks at the same time on click of the button. So here's some sample code assuming this is what you want. If you have any doubts just ask. And i have added just sample Email Validation Using RegExp in JavaSript at the end of the code as a function.. Get the idea, Hope this helped you,, 
//

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Button1 Click
    $("button").click(function(){

        //initialize inputs here
        var email =$("#email").val;
        var input1=$("#input1").val;
        //Validate Inputs Here
        if(IsEmail(email)==true && input1!=""){

            return true
        }
        else{

            return false;
        }

        //Loading the first content after validating inputs 
        $("#content").load("<?php echo base_url().'survey/categories' ?>");     

        //To Trigger the other button   
        $('#button1').trigger('click');

        });

        //Button1 Trigger Will fire Click event 
        $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#content").load("<?php echo base_url().'survey/budget_overview' ?>");
    });
});


    //Email Validation In JavaScript
    function IsEmail(email) {
          var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
          return regex.test(email);
        }
```

Comment: yeah you are right. when they click on continue it has to check for validation and if everything is validated it has to change the div content. please give some sample code for this including validating name and email.

Comment: why don't you search google for validating text input and email; there are hundreds of example...

Comment: check the code i have provided, i have added a basic email validating function at the end of the code.